# Flutter: PendingIntents not received when code is executed through flutter

Tags: android-intent, flutter

I wrote some native android code in java, which I need for my app build in flutter. In this code, I schedule notifications using `PendingIntent`. When I run the code when editing the android part (opening the android folder in android studio and running `app`), my notifications show and work like expected. However, when I open the dart/flutter part of my app and run `main.dart` my all functionality to do with `PendingIntent`s breaks.

A strange artifact in this is that it only seems to happen on Broadcasts, and not on Activities. To explain: The main tap action is to bring the `MainActivity` to the foreground, which always works. I've also added action buttons to the notification which execute broadcasts, which show the earlier described problem.

I've tried looking at my `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle`, and checking if all my libraries from androidX are updated (also double checked the dependencies).

The code for building the notification (showing it simply uses `NotificationManager.notify()`)

```java
private static NotificationCompat.Builder getBuilder(Context context, NotificationData data) {
        Intent tapIntent = new Intent(context, getMainActivityClass(context));
//      tapIntent.setAction(ACTION_OPEN);
        PendingIntent tapPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, tapIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, SnoozeBroadcast.class);
//      snoozeIntent.setAction(ACTION_SNOOZE);
        snoozeIntent.putExtra(SnoozeBroadcast.SNOOZE_ID, data.id);
        snoozeIntent.putExtra(SnoozeBroadcast.SNOOZE_TITLE, data.title);
        snoozeIntent.putExtra(SnoozeBroadcast.SNOOZE_MESSAGE, data.message);
        snoozeIntent.putExtra(SnoozeBroadcast.SNOOZE_DELAY, data.snoozeDelay);
        PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, snoozeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(context, CancelBroadcast.class);
//      cancelIntent.setAction(ACTION_CANCEL);
        cancelIntent.putExtra(CancelBroadcast.CANCEL_ID, data.id);
        PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, cancelIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        if(snoozePendingIntent == null) System.out.println("snooze null");
        if(cancelPendingIntent == null) System.out.println("cancel null");

        // TODO: get channel from arguments
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(data.title)
                .setContentText(data.message)
                .setContentIntent(tapPendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .addAction(R.drawable.notification_icon, "Snooze", snoozePendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.notification_icon, "Cancel", cancelPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        return builder;
    }
```

The code for receiving the `CancelBroadcast`

```java
public class CancelBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String CANCEL_ID = "com.example.my_app.cancel_id";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("received");
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        int id = data.getInt(CANCEL_ID);
        FlutterNotificationsPlugin.cancelById(context, id);
    }
}
```

As said before, I expect the `onReceive()` method to be executed - which write a line to `stdout` - when I press the "Snooze" button on the notification (which shows fine). This happens when running `app` but not when running `main.dart`.

Comment: How did you get this to work?

Comment: I did not. The problem was in compilation. I compiled the platform specific code separately, somehow creating a discrepancy between the flutter and java code. A clean rebuild solved all my issues.